# How do you iterate html tags to get innerText with wildcards in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

For educational purposes I am trying to get the reviews of this page https://www.tripadvisor.es/Restaurant_Review-g294308-d4754017-Reviews-or10-TAC_ROLL-Quito_Pichincha_Province.html. I have 10 reviews per page and I have these set of html selectors (my code used to get all the 10 comments from every page but the page was updated):

```
#review_593124597 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
#review_583146930 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
#review_577877496 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
#review_572957932 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
#review_571417105 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
#review_565883882 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
#review_564612180 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
#review_554301618 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)
```

The 2 things that change is the review id and the 4th div (going between nth-child 4 and 5, **I dont know if these also affects the result of the innerText**). I am trying to get the innerText of these elements but I have no luck. The code I am currently using is:

```
const comentarios = 'div[id^=review_] > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1)' 
const comnetarioLength = 'partial_entry';

let listLength = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
    window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel).length;
}, comnetarioLength);

console.log(listLength);
```

The following is my old code that used to work but the page was updated and I dont know what exactly I have to do, since **I only get the first innerText of every page**:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= listLength; i++) {

    let selectorComentarios = comentarios.replace("Index", i); //<--I know 
    //this is supposed to be different
    let comentario = await page.evaluate((sel) => { // Let's create variables and store values...

        try {
            let comentarioText = document.querySelector(sel).innerText;
            return comentarioText;
        }
        catch (e) { }

    }, selectorComentarios);
    console.log(comentario);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth to provide a page URL and a screenshot of the elements you need to get `innerText` of. It is hard to understand the task completely from the partial code fragments.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt ok and thx for the suggestion. I updated the post.

Comment: It looks like you could just get all the elements with class `prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx` with `document.getElementsByClassName('prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx')`, it returns the 10 comments, just iterate overthat NodeList to get the innerText of each element.

Comment: It seems even the `'p.partial_entry'` selector can be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? This script outputs an array with the first 10 reviews.

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://www.tripadvisor.es/Restaurant_Review-g294308-d4754017-Reviews-or10-TAC_ROLL-Quito_Pichincha_Province.html');

    const reviews = await page.evaluate(
      () => [...document.querySelectorAll('p.partial_entry')]
              .map( ({ innerText }) => innerText )
    )

    console.log(reviews);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thats awesome! It solved my problem. I was going to take a long route but this actually made it so simple. Thx.